# Where and when did the negative connotations of "manipulation" appear?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, etymology, history

When we think of manipulating objects, we might think of a juggler, magician, chef, etc.

When we think of manipulating *people*, however, it almost always comes with negative connotations. These fascinate me as we're perfectly prepared to have our behaviour altered by *charsimatic* people, but not manipulative ones.

When I look up the origins of the word, the [online etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=manipulation) tells me it comes from Latin of *filling the hand*, to *manipule*, meaning a measure, to *skillful handling of objects*, to the skillful handling of people.

I'm also familiar with NLP, [Neil Strauss's "The Game"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060554738), and [Cialdini's "Influence"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006124189X).

Was there any negative connotation of *manipulation* before these?

Are there any other words that carry a more definite negative that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Here's [he could manipulate any woman but his wife](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7OQEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=%22manipulate%22&source=bl&ots=KetSZxmgz7&sig=3o41SBzYKas2ntWr4AZMhdDIOiM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gVc1UJaYEMTF0QWppYDwBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22manipulate%22&f=false) from 1839. I doubt the writer meant "fondle".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think he makes it pretty explicit in the later text - thank you for that! Still looking for more though (it's for a talk on respect for people).

Comment: I'm not sure the etymology of *manipulate*, or knowledge of when it first came to be used in the sense you're focussed on, will be much help. But the key distinction is that it means *to influence **covertly, surreptitiously***. With *charismatic* people, there's no implication that they're in any way secretive about what they're doing. There's nothing inherently disrespectful about seeking to influence people, but deception and secrecy aren't really compatible with respect.

Comment: Who says charismatic people can't be manipulative? Often these are the *most* manipulative people — politicians, for example.

Comment: Thanks again @FumbleFingers, that's a really useful insight. Do you have any links to definitions that include the notion of covert or surreptitious behavior please?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *manipulate* in your linked text means "hypnotise [by means of touch]". See page 50 of [Animal Magnetism, 1837](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=045BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA50).

Comment: @GarethRees Hypnosis has also been described to me as a form of manipulation (I've got training in hypnotherapy) so happy to accept this too. There are similar negative connotations around hypnosis as well.

Comment: @Robusto: I don't say charismatic people *can't* be manipulative - just that (for me at least) describing someone as charismatic doesn't automatically imply they're also manipulative - any more than it implies they're black, or female, or whatever.

Comment: @Gareth Rees: Haha I didn't bother reading the full context. So obviously the writer did mean "touch" - but by "fondle", I meant "indulge in sexual caressing", and he certainly didn't mean that!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was addressing the OP, who explicitly makes that statement in his second paragraph.

Comment: @Robusto: oic. Yes, they are effectively *chalk and cheese* - not, as OP seems to imply, opposite ends of some semantic spectrum spanning "favourable/unfavourable descriptions of people who influence others".

Comment: @Robusto That semantic spectrum is how the two words are *commonly* regarded. I was hoping to get another word to reset that spectrum (Machiavellian fits nicely) and some idea of how "manipulation" came to be regarded so negatively in the first place. For context, here's the blog that set me off: http://kaverjody.com/manipulate-to-coach-no/ - you can see my response in the comments there. (Also, I am female).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a more negative word meaning *manipulative*, I'd say **Machiavellian** fills the bill. It means unscrupulously cunning and manipulative.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer your first question ("Was there any negative connotation of *manipulation* before these?"). Your second question seems hard to answer: how can we possibly know which words and senses you are not aware of?

In the *OED* the earliest citations given that have the negative connotation are this one for *manipulate*:

> 1862   T. Carlyle *Hist. Friedrich II of Prussia* III. xii. xi. 358   He had got his Electors manipulated, tickled to his purpose.

And this one for *manipulation*:

> 1875   W. Stubbs *Constit. Hist.* II. xvii. 611   The third estate..was only too susceptible of royal manipulation.

So this sense is much older than neuro-linguistic programming (1970s), *Influence* (2001), or *The Game* (2005). You might want to read about the idea of [recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion).

Comment: Not suffering from recency illusion, or I wouldn't have posted requests for more info. You might want to read about the idea of double-loop learning. Thanks for the excerpts anyway. FumbleFingers has given me 1839 in the comments so we know it's earlier than these.